# How to make the following math equation have vertical equal distance?

Tags: math-mode

With the following code

```
-E\left[\frac{\partial^2 \ln p(z,\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}\right] =
\frac{1}{\displaystyle\frac{2}{N_0}\int_0^T \left(\frac{\partial
s(t,\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2dt-
\frac{\partial^2 \ln p(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}}
```

produces

[image]

How can I make the left hand side bigger?

Comment: IMO there is no need to change this. BTW: always post full minimal examples instead of posting sniplets. Then it is easier to copy and test your code.

Comment: the left hand side would look odd if you make it bigger (I wouldn't have used `\displaystyle` on the right either, if you do not like the fraction form on the right use `(....)^{-1}` instead

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much. I use -1 method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have textstyle fractions and integral in the denominator, I suggest you use the `\medsize` command from `nccmath` (~80% of `displaystyle`). In addition one can simplify the typing of partial derivatives with the `\diffp` command from `esdiff`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts}
\usepackage{nccmath, esdiff}

 \begin{document}

\[ -\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\partial^2 \ln p(z,\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}\right] =
\frac{1}{\medmath{\frac{2}{N_0}\int_0^T \biggl(\diffp{s(t,\theta)}{\theta}\biggr)^{\mkern-5mu 2}dt
-\diffp[2]{\ln p(\theta)}{\theta}}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation of the "`^{-1}`" method. Note the use of `\biggl[` and `\biggr]` to assure that the square brackets have the same (vertical) size as on the left-hand side of the equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\begin{document}
\[
-\E \left[
\frac{\partial^2\ln p(z,\theta)}{\partial\theta^2}
\right] =
\biggl[
\frac{2}{N_0}\int_0^T \! \left(\frac{\partial
s(t,\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2 dt-
\frac{\partial^2\ln p(\theta)}{\partial\theta^2}
\biggr]^{-1}
\]
\end{document}
```